# How to fill a select list with AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

[image]

I want to fill the options from a select with AJAX. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code in my View:

```
 $(function() {
    $.getJSON("Animes/GetCategories", null, function(data) {
        var options = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[x]['CategoryID'] + '">' + data[x]['CategoryNom'] + '</option>';
        }
        console.log(options);
        $('#lstCat').html(options);

    });
});
```

The code in my Controller :

```
public JsonResult GetCategories() {
    var affCat = from cats in db.Categories
    select new {
        CategoryID = cats.CategoryID,
        CategoryNom = cats.CategoryNom
    };

    return Json(affCat, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The code of the select in my View:

```
<select id="lstCat">
    //Don't know what to place in the select
    <option>?</option>
</select><br />
```

Comment: Oh dear... This is a horrible mess of combined js frameworks. Is there actually Angular in play here? If so there's no reason to do jQuery like this at all.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using Angularjs, Try to use to fully instead of mixing with jquery

try like this

**Js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.categoryList = [];
    $.getJSON("Animes/GetCategories", null, function(data) {
        $scope.categoryList = data;
    });
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <select id="lstCat" ng-options="category.CategoryID as category.CategoryNom for category in categoryList">
   </select>
</div>
```

By the way for html jquery have `.html()` to append html . .val() if for controls only

like this

```
$('#lstCat').html(options);
```

and from your html remove option

Like this

```
<select id="lstCat">
</select>
```

Comment: It was my bad, I added the Angularjs tag, but I don't use it. I don't know why I added it

Comment: Then try my second sugession that i mentioned in my answer . `$('#lstCat').html(options);`

Comment: it's not working, I wil paste my code in the top, I don't know how to proceed, I'm really tired of this thing that doesn't work correctly

Comment: what's `console.log(options);` print ??  Can you provide that screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

`val` is not used for adding html.

Instead of:

```
$('#lstCat').val(options);
```

try:

```
$('#lstCat').html(options);
```